# Json results sorting not working in php

Tags: php, json, sorting

Sorting not working..

my controller page

```
$price = $_POST['price'];

        $search = $_POST['search'];
        $cat_id = $_POST['category'];

        $post1 = file_get_contents("...?search=".$search."&category=".$cat_id);
        $products = CJSON::decode($post1, true);
        if($price == 1)
        {
            function prod($a, $b) {
                        return $a["retail_price"] - $b["retail_price"];
                }

                 usort($products, "prod");                                                                                                                                                                                                   

            echo "<pre>";print_r($products);die;
        }
```

it does not print the result in a sorted order..
$products is an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11027
                    [title] => SPIDERMAN ENGRAVED LIGHTER
                    [barcode] => LEN-0022
                    [qty] => 8
                    [url] => http://www.ebay.com/itm/-/381279328138?
                    [retail_price] => 9.99
                    [category] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 34
                            [name] => ENGRAVED LIGHTERS
                        )

                    [bin] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 346
                            [name] => F10
                        )

                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [small] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal//timthumb.php?src=/files/products/dscn124900.jpg&w=30
                                    [middle] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal//timthumb.php?src=/files/products/dscn124900.jpg&w=100
                                    [source] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal/files/products/dscn124900.jpg
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11548
                    [title] => SPIDER MAN Black Lighter
                    [barcode] => LEN-0067
                    [qty] => 6
                    [url] => http://www.ebay.com/itm/-/361369988738?
                    [retail_price] => 10.99
                    [category] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 34
                            [name] => ENGRAVED LIGHTERS
                        )

                    [bin] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 346
                            [name] => F10
                        )

                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [small] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal//timthumb.php?src=/files/products/len-00670.jpg&w=30
                                    [middle] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal//timthumb.php?src=/files/products/len-00670.jpg&w=100
                                    [source] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal/files/products/len-00670.jpg
                                )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

This is the result i get when array is sorted by the retail_price.Sorting does not work ,why is it so???? Can anyone help me with this????
Waiting for the response...........

Comment: looks from the structure of the array like it should probably be  `usort($products[0], "prod");` Also you haven't said whether you want them sorted by price ascending or descending. Lastly, beware of the caution in the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) regarding non-integer values. In the example data you've given you'll get away with it because the calculation returns a whole number, but if your prices are, e.g. 10.99 and 8.50 it may not sort as you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$products` is not just an array, but it's an array in an array:

```
$products = array( array( product1, product2 ) );
```

You don't want that surrounding array, so just do

```
    $post1 = file_get_contents("...?search=".$search."&category=".$cat_id);
    $data = CJSON::decode($post1, true);
    $products = $data[0];

    //...
```

---

Site note: You shouldn't declare a function within the running code. This tends to result in strange errors.

Instead just declare it in the top, or use an anonymous function.

```
$prod = function($a, $b) {
    return $a["retail_price"] - $b["retail_price"];
}

usort($products, $prod);
```